# Name of sound when final drops of water drain down basin

Tags: single-word-requests, sounds

What is the name of the sound when the last remaining drops of water are about to drain down the plug hole of a basin when the plug is removed?

Here is a [sample](http://www.sounddogs.com/sound-effects/25/mp3/479951_SOUNDDOGS__wa.mp3). The last part is not loud enough for one to hear that characteristic sound.

EDIT (FF): [Here's](http://www.soundsnap.com/node/97677) a better sound sample, where the change in tone just at the end is really clear.

Comment: what you call glug is what I'm saying, do you know how is it called in the mainstream or colloquial context?

Comment: @FumbleFingers never mind, "glug" is specific enough as a search in Google suggested me, thanks very much

Comment: @FumbleFingers sure, no problem

Comment: I'm Southern UK, but here's at least one instance from Scotland: [Glug glug glug, it goes down the plughole](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22glug%22+%22goes+down+the+plughole%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right from when the water first starts to suck air into the eddy going down a plug-hole, the sound it makes is **gurgling** - defined by OED as *the noise made by liquid escaping intermittently from a vessel*.

Personally, I call the sound made at the very *end* a **glug** (OED: *a word formed to imitate an inarticulate sound*).

*Glug* functions as a verb, as well as a noun. Obviously, if water *glugs*, that just means the water is *making that sound*. But in another common usage, to *glug* means to drink (often, the *last drops of*) something noisily and/or hastily - [glug the last](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22glug%20the%20last%22&oq=%22glug%20the%20last%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) dregs in a glass of beer, for example.

Comment: Gah. Major semantic satiation on "glug" by the time I read this all the way through. :)

Comment: @Martha: If you're down the pub with "drinking buddies" in the UK, and someone is just about to get another round of beers in, he might well hold your almost-finished glass in front of you and say *"Glug that!"*.